# Can/Should people review flags of their own post?

Tags: support, flagging

I had flagged an answer as needing update due to missing several points after edits were made for clarification on the original post, and a phrase that said I looked ignorant (due to the lack of knowledge of gendered languages).

The flag was denied by the same person that wrote the answer.

I wouldn't like to link the answer due to it being irrelevant for the subject.
Is this possible by design? Should people be able to review flags on their posts (Q or A)?

Answer (score 3):

Only moderators can see flags, and normally we rarely deal with the flags on our own posts. Having said that I do deal with some of mine from time to time these days.

I got in the habit by necessity when the strike was on. If it was me, then feel free to discuss it with me and I'll have another look.

Comment: I don't think it was, and it really isn't relevant, i wanted to foucus on, Should mods even be able to see flags on their own posts ?

Comment: I don't see why not. But it's not up to us.

Comment: Im just thinking it can create a situation where mods could be as rule breaking as they want if they can just deny and overule all flags

Comment: There's plenty of mods with their own agendas on stack exchange, but we have a good team here in my opinion. You can always discuss your concerns privately or escalate.

Comment: Hey there @Or4ng3h4t I did some analysis to logs and what you mention in this post and this is what I can say... If you are talking about the "other"-typed flag you flagged on an answer under your most recent post (one answer where I commented about Latin-derived languages), then it was I who handled that flag... not the user who answered... I even wrote a comment (which you can see) when handling it that hinted it was I... Non-mod users can't see those flags nor handle them (at least to non-mod users, mods can see who handled it).

Comment: @DarkCygnus - was it on one of my answers, per chance?

Comment: @TheDemonLord I'm being vague in purpose, and if it's yours or not doesn't matter. The point is that only mods can handle Answer Flags and sometimes we even refrain from doing so and instead let another mod handle it. Thus it's not possible for non-mod users to handle their own flags.

Comment: @DarkCygnus - I thought so ;)

Comment: @TheDemonLord No I flagged another answer.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yes the flag is question is the one you are mentioning, and I figured I was wrong, but I think the original question is still relevant, want me to remove it ?

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t no need to remove anything. It seems you have the clarification you asked for so everything is going as it should. Don't be shy to ask for clarification any time. Just make sure you don't have bad intentions when asking. Mods are here to assist.